# Visual basic script excel returning no Value?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't seem to find the problem.

Why is the following code only returning #VALUE in stead of the real value? When I use a Breakpoint, I see that the retval is indeed receiving only the numeric values as demanded. Retval is indeed giving the value to "GetValues", but when the function is finished only "#VALUE" is appearing in the cell...

The goal is to continue only with numeric values from a specific cell. example:
In Cell C17 there is: "GPRS (2271215 bytes)"
Then in D18: "=GetValues(C17)"

any ideas? code below:

```
Function GetValues(ByVal s As String) As String

' Variables needed.   '
Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

' Initialise return string to empty                       '
retval = ""

' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
'   return string.                                        '
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
    End If
Next

' Then return the return string.                          '
GetValues = retval

Return

End Function
```

Comment: Remove the `Return` line.

Comment: You might want to remove the quotes around `"0"` and `"9"` too - you're using a logical operator with a string, I would cast using `CInt(Mid(s, i, 1))` instead - just to be sure.

Comment: I'd use `IsNumeric` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function GetValues(ByVal s As String) As String

Dim retval As String   
Dim i As Integer       
Dim x As Long 'add a variable to receive the numeric value
                '
retval = ""

For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= 0 And Mid(s, i, 1) <= 9 Then    
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)       
    End If
Next

x = CLng(retval) 'convert retval to a number
GetValues = x                    
End Function
```